# CSS responsive grid layout with auto fitting to screen width

Tags: javascript, layout, css-grid

I try to figure out how airbnb display photo galery using grid layout.

[example1](https://www.airbnb.fr/rooms/37122502/photos?check_in=2021-06-18&check_out=2021-06-25&federated_search_id=40204e8d-57f7-40a8-929d-b0343b91b7bb&source_impression_id=p3_1620220595_xiQTq5ggNJBj04TT&guests=1&adults=1)
[example2](https://www.airbnb.fr/rooms/31883127/photos?check_in=2021-06-18&check_out=2021-06-25&federated_search_id=f73a9baa-e6e5-432a-9548-eef1c972be94&source_impression_id=p3_1620224229_fPIqJsQf233sEUnX&guests=1&adults=1)

It is not about grid layout itself but how they determine when display 1, 2 or even 3 image per rows and how they can determine the numbers of rows.

It seems that each photo gallery layout is unique.

In first I thought that for each row a random value between 1 and 3 is given to determine how many images should be displayed but layout is always the same.

Does anyone have any clues to achieve this kind of layout with a variant number of photos ?

EDIT :

based on comment masonry structure is something like this

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="item1"></div>
    <div id="item2"></div>
    <div id="item3"></div>
    <div id="item4"></div>
    <div id="item5"></div>
    <div id="item6"></div>
    <div id="item7"></div>
</div>
```

but examples are ( simplified )

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="item1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="item2"></div>
        <div id="item3"></div>
        <div id="item4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="item5"></div>
        <div id="item6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="item7"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT 2

Other example

[example4](https://www.airbnb.fr/rooms/48679571/photos?check_in=2021-06-01&check_out=2021-06-29&display_extensions%5B%5D=MONTHLY_STAYS&federated_search_id=5879d570-772d-4b35-8fc6-a7e90f1cfacd&source_impression_id=p3_1620241839_BVVss0Pc9PPAlcKT)

Same number of images as example 1 layout is different

In example 1 first row containing 3 items
In example 4 first row containing 1 item

What could be conditioning that choice ?

Answer (score -1):

**1.** That is called Masonry Layouts, and airBnb just has 2 layouts one vertical and one horizontal

Follow this official MDN Doc to learn more on the [Masonry layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Masonry_Layout)

**2.** Now for the layout the link you shared as example 1 has vertical images that are column layout and an example-2 which has the first image that goes side-ways is row layout.

**3.**  How they decide which layout to use there are 2 important things to understand here first is the **viewport** that decided the primary layout to be shown, Second number of links open [yes.. you can track how many link a user has opened in a browser,Hence the tabs in chorme and firefox are famous], this tell the SSR[server-side-rendered page] engine to rotate the layout

**Bonus** An Artical for you to self-learn [Learn CSS Grid by recreating familiar layouts: Airbnb, Youtube and more](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learning-css-grid-through-recreating-airbnb-youtube-and-more-399c71377eaa/)

Comment: thanks for your awnser, but it doesn't help in anyway rotate the layout ? thanks for the tutorial but as you can notice the airbnb layout teached is not the same as now

Comment: it's a 2017 article and it does not work the recent layout style but is ment to give a headstart as to what they have under the hood.. 

the Row and Col make a lot of difference in Masonry layout you should really dig deeper on goole about it

Comment: if I disturb the stackoverflow community it's because I didn't find anything that's helped me but let me thank you to spend minutes of your time to be the only awser me.

Comment: I read some articles about masonry but they dont really help masonry layout assumes that the browser display images according viewport and grid-template properties ( all child in container ) but airbnb layouts display photos using rows ( for same number of photos more or less row )  and for same imaze size sometimes 1 images in a row sometimes 2 or even 3

Comment: Masonry layout using only css grid alone cannot get you a mixed layout for that you need to use JavaScript.. and there are a ton of Packages that can help you generate layout.. take an example of this guy 

David DeSandro [https://desandro.com/] He has an amazing npm package called 
masonry-layout [https://masonry.desandro.com/] if you visit the layout page on this website you shall see how plain old html is dynamically converted into various layout

Comment: == Since i ran out of space in ealier comment ==
Visit the options page to understand how the css properties are manuplated to get the desired output such as Horizontal Layout, Element sizing for 2,3 or 5 images per row/col and much more..Here is a sample codepen 
https://codepen.io/marcobiedermann/pen/oYvoQL

Comment: Masonry sounds good but seems not to be the solution codepen shows that items are all into the same container and there is no row unlike into link

Comment: It one way to use the same plugin.. the official docs from [https://masonry.desandro.com/] have a different approach to the same Design/pattern whatever you wish to call it.

Masonry Layouts are fluid by nature it's up to the designer how he/she wants to style it, there is no specific way which can be labeled right or wrong

Comment: And I agree with that but question is more about how determine how many items display in a row in airbnb use case. Why 1 in a case and 2 or 3 in another when images size are equals ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231999/discussion-between-nishant-sham-vispute-and-akio).